# Skip Hibernate validation on save

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I need to skip one particular field's validation (**a**) on persist if the value of a different field (**b**) is X

```java
ClassA{
  @Check
  String a;
  String b;
  @Validation1
  String c
}
```

When I do **entityManager.persist(a)**, I want to:

- If (b=X) skip @Check validation
- If (b!=X), perform @Check validation

The rest of the validations (in this case @Validation1) shouldn't be affected

Is this possible?

Comment: Why don't you create two different classes ?

Comment: not sure if that's possible from an effort pov, since this is a core class in my project, and that kind of change will require a lot of effort and regression testing, it will impact a big part of the project

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the situation using class validators + groups:

```
@ComplexCheck
ClassA{
  @Check(groups={CustomGroup.class})
  String a;
  String b;
  @Validation1
  String c
}
```

By default, on persist, **@Check** will be skipped. **@ComplexCheck** will be performed, where I can do the logic I need:

- If b=X, I explicitly skip @Check validation, inside the @ComplexCheck logic
- If b!=X, I explicitly perform @Check validation, inside the @ComplexCheck logic (by means of validatior.validate())